# W/System.err: .MainActivity$1.onResponse

Tags: android

I am trying to parse Json it will show error

```
final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               // Log.d(TAG, response);
                try {

                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d(TAG, jobj.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue reQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        reQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Here is my api
http://159.65.89.76/userApi/categories

Comment: Show full error stack trace. Also check whether your server returns a JSON string.

Comment: It seems that your response is not valid JSON string. Use a JSON validator (there are plenty online tools) to identify what's wrong with your response.